# Is there a benefit in doing pthread_exit after pthread_join in main()?

Tags: c

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/join.c

Please see the code in the link above.

1. Is there any benefit in doing pthread_exit after pthread_join in main()?

Comment: From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769628/using-pthread-exit-and-pthread-join-pthread-exit-doesnt-terminate-the-calling), it appears that `pthread_exit` terminates the calling thread immediately, so in `main` it is equivalent to a `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the POSIX specification of [`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html), there isn't much benefit to using `pthread_exit()` instead of either `exit()` or `_exit()` or `return`.  Nominally, it means that `atexit()` handlers are not executed, and it might mean that file streams are not flushed — more like `_exit()`.  In the context of the sample code, it seems unnecessary.